# Как задать стиль dropmenu у antd без CSS

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы dropmenu отображалось полностью текст строки, а не часть его

```
<Select
    value={val}
    onChange={this.changeHandler}
>
    <Option key={posVal}>
        {name}
    </Option>
</Select>
```

name имеет переменную длину и не всегда влезает в необходимый размер окна.
Подключать внешний CSS файл не имеется возможности.
Скролить тоже не вариант

[image: 1]]

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы указали, какое плагин для `Select` используете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В api есть свойсвтво `dropdownMatchSelectWidth` по дефолту стоит `true`, если поставить `false` все будет как надо